# Debug log for exe files in Win7?

Tags: windows-7

I have an executable that does not startup as expected on Windows 7, in fact, it just (seemingly) does nothing at all.

Is there a log or debugging feature in Windows 7 that could help me find out why its not starting up?

Comment: You *might* find something in the Event Logs, but any logging would have to be performed by the application itself, and would therefore be application-specific. (This excludes crash/error reporting, but a message should pop up first in those cases.)

Comment: Yeah, the application logs remain completely empty, as if the exe is doing absolutely nothing.  Thanks, I will check out the Event Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to run it in compatibility mode.

You could use Systems Internals Process Explorer to see if the process consumes CPU and in which functions the threads of the process are. You can even get a stack trace for all threads. If you need more data, you might want to use a debugger, but for a fast look Process Explorer might be a good idea.

You could also use Systems Internals Process Monitor to see the registry and file access operations of the process. Maybe you can see that one of the last accesses fails and then the process hangs.